# Webcam not working in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, dell, webcam

I run Ubuntu 22.04 on a Dell, and the internal webcam does not work (No device found). It shows the following error:

[image]

Comment: Try looking if there is a camera. Run `ls /dev` and look for a `video0` or `video1` device. Another method is `lsusb` (inbuilt webcams use USB) and you should see the camera in the list.

Comment: I didn't find video0 or video1 !

Comment: you should add that info to your question. Sorry I can't help, maybe someone else will.

Comment: For me the problem was the shutter was closed. 
Please see this: https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-in/inspiron-14-5410-2-in-1-laptop/inspiron-5410-2-in-1-setup-and-specifications/using-the-privacy-shutter?guid=guid-514df42a-261e-493a-9ddb-08f3d2e3b8ab&lang=en-us